# Vertical align "link text" to middle of li item (and make text-size scale accordingly to fit li container)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Wow, 
I hope my title made sense

I made a full page navigation, wrapped in a list, the way it's supposed to... Am i right?,
So now i have a few questions:

1  Is it possible to vertically center my links within the list items ?
2  Can i make my text so it fits in the list items when i scale up or down the viewport
3  Bonus question why are the changes i made to link:visited not visible

Jquery solutions are allowed ;)

I've already tried different solutions i've found online but none seem to work in my case
     like (use vertical-align an put a paragraph tag around my links)
      or  (use display:table) etc..

Well here is my code hope it makes sense (do not laugh with my newbie coding style)

Greetzz Djlzz

You can visit the full site @ http://codepen.io/DJLZZ/pen/BeLHl
To make some sense out of my coding logic, lol... and to visually see what i'm doing and why ;)

All help is appreciated

HTML:

```
    <div class="nav">
    <ul id="navsound">
        <li> <a href="index.html"       >     Home   </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="music.html"       >     Music  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="about.html"       >     About  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="pics.html"        >      Pics  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="video.html"       >     Video  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="guestbook.html"   > Guestbook  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="agenda.html"      >    Agenda  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="store.html"       >     Store  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html"     >   Contact  </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="links.html"       >     Links  </a> </li>
    </ul>
```

Css

```
.nav  {     z-index:10;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:75%;
    width:90%;
    margin-top:0.5%;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    }

.nav ul { display:block;
    height:100%;
     list-style-type:none;
    }

.nav li { display:inline-block;
    height:9%;margin-bottom:0.5%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
    }

.nav a:link {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ff9900;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }   

.nav a:hover{
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #ffffff;
    transform: scale(1.05,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05,1); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1); /* Safari en Chrome */
    transition-property:transform;
    transition-duration:0.4s;
    }

.nav a:visited {display:inline-block;
                color: #ff9900;
                background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) }
```

Thank you my precious "Code-junkies"

Comment: Why are you doing `nav li { height: 9%? }`?

Comment: I have 10 nav li items... I want them to fill the entire nav ul that said they all have 0.5% margins hence 10x9%=90% 10x0.5%=5% together=95% 5% to spare on the bottom  Yeah you're right 9.05% would be better

Comment: is this what you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qemfB ?

Comment: First of all Thank you for taking the time to review my humble code

Comment: And most of all even digging in ;) My answer is.. Yes in a way that is what i want on the other hand (i see what you did there)...Now the links don't fill the entire height of the .nav at 75%height anymore You see where i'm getting (there must be a way to dynamically resize the text to fit the ".nav li") Hope i make sense "Cheers"

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/ just found out about this maybe this could bring me a solution i'll keep you guy's posted

Comment: Your text isn't vertically centered because the line-height is taller than the height of the `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css transforms to vertically center them, I put together a demo here http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/qDtkc

Comment: Yes thank you !!! Looks like a very elegant solution beautiful ! and yes this is in a way exactly what i asked just a bit to literally (but that's my fault) I think i'm going to imply some of it. But i can't grant you "solved" Because you see now the visitors have to click on a to tiny area but i'm going to look further into it and keep you guy's posted trough my little codepen @ http://codepen.io/DJLZZ/pen/BeLHl

Comment: I can't thank you guy's enough for taking the time to look into this... this coding stuff is truly becoming addictive

Comment: By using "vh" as measurement for my text is kind of the workaround of the to small clickable area by applying my "on hover" transformation to the "li" instead of the "a" itself solved the other problem i had with @Josh solution so where i am right now comes pretty close to what i intended to do it's all just a bit laggy "because i now have 2 transformations on these "li" items? Now that you guys can see what i try to accomplish isn't there a more elegant solution to this, what i have come to understand is that if you set a height for "a" there is no way to center the text inside of it "right?"

Comment: You can center the text inside the "a" only if you've set an explicit height. If you're using, say 20vh as the "a" height, setting a line-height of 20vh should vertically center the text. Hope this helps